# how to free memory allocated by g_thread_init

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-leaks, free, glib

I would like to know if it's possible to free the memory allocated by 
`g_thread_init(NULL)`

here is my code :

```
int main(void)
{    
g_thread_init(NULL);            
g_thread_exit(NULL); 
}
```

and the valgrind output :

```
==1944== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1944==     in use at exit: 8,910 bytes in 119 blocks
==1944==   total heap usage: 159 allocs, 40 frees, 15,033 bytes allocated
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible, but I don't remember where I read the explanation

Comment: Maybe there are some static variables which will never be free while application running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g_thread_init()` is a run-once function that does setup for the multithreading support in GLib.  The memory it allocates is never freed.

In newer versions of GLib (>= 2.32), `g_thread_init()` is effectively a no-op, and you don't need to call it at all -- all of the multithreading setup is done automatically when your program starts.

So the answer to your question is: you can't, and you shouldn't be trying to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the info about GLib 2.32 :)